# valgrind: unable to located error detected by valgrind

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

`valgrind` detects an error in my C++ code, but unable to tell at which line that error happens. Here is the report from valgrind:

```
==11757== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11757==     in use at exit: 120 bytes in 1 blocks
==11757==   total heap usage: 66,334 allocs, 66,333 frees, 137,141,930 bytes allocated
==11757== 
==11757== 120 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==11757==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==11757==    by 0x8097788: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:68)
==11757==    by 0xFAB5EB2: ??? (in /lib/libselinux.so.1)
==11757==    by 0xFABE465: ??? (in /lib/libselinux.so.1)
==11757==    by 0xFAAE2D2: ??? (in /lib/libselinux.so.1)
==11757==    by 0x7FF0009D6: ???
==11757==    by 0x6B72776164642F6F: ???
==11757==    by 0x6C6F6F542F75542E: ???
==11757==    by 0x4846472F7374696A: ???
==11757==    by 0x474F4846472F474E: ???
==11757==    by 0x3100742D006E6C2D: ???
==11757==    by 0x30303200732CFF: ???
==11757== 
==11757== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11757==    definitely lost: 120 bytes in 1 blocks
==11757==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11757==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11757==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11757==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11757== 
==11757== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11757== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Since my code is too long I can't post it here. From the report, there is one block unfreed. But it is really weird that `valgrind` does not tell me which line in my code allocates that memory. Any help?
NOTE: I did add the flag -g in the Makefile when compiling the code. Please let me know if you need more information.
My `Makefile`:

```
# source files. 
SRC = main.cpp Fonix.cpp TraceDetect.cpp ImageT.cpp
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
OUT = out.ln

INCS_DIR = /vol/fonix/enterprise/include/
LIBS_DIR = /vol/fonix/enterprise/lib

# include directories
INCLUDES = -I$(INCS_DIR)

# C++ compiler flags (-g -O2 -Wall)
CCFLAGS = -g -fPIC -fopenmp -Wall -O0

# compiler
CCC = g++

# library paths
LIBS = -L$(LIBS_DIR) -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_ml  -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_gpu  -lopencv_flann -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lswscale -lswresample -lavdevice -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lz -lbz2 -lpthread -lsuperlu_4.3 -lblas

.SUFFIXES: .cpp

default: $(OUT)

.cpp.o:
    $(CCC) $(INCLUDES) $(CCFLAGS) -D_DEBUG=1 -c $< -o $@

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CCC) $(OBJ) $(LIBS) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(OUT) Makefile.bak
```

Comment: Looks like your program doesn't contain debugging symbols. If you specify `-g` when compiling, and don't strip the program, you should see function names and line numbers.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I did add _-g_ when compiling. Thanks to it I fixed several memory leak error in my code. But only this one does not show the function name and error. That is why I ask.

Comment: It is possible that this leak comes from `libselinux` and you have no control over it. You should still see `_start` method of your program in stack trace though. Try updating `libselinux` and see, if this still happens.

Comment: Try adding "--num-callers=50" to the valgrind command line to get a deeper stack -- by default, you only get fewer levels than that, and so your entry point may be deeper than that.

Comment: JohnH: Adding _--num-callers=50_ makes the report longer with lots of lost memory addresses e.g. _0x7070737376632F71: ???_. But it still doesn't help.  
@Banthar: I'm not root so unable to update that library, but will try on another machine with newer version of _libselinux_. How do I "see _start method of your program in stack trace"?

Comment: @Banthar I have run it on a different machine running Ubuntu LTS 12.04 and Valgrind is happy now (my old machine runs Ubuntu 10.04). Please put it as answer so that I can accept it.